# MonoDevelop 2.4: Help finding a dll

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am trying to build a MonoDevelop 2.4 add-in but I need the dll with the namespace of: MonoDevelop.Projects.Gui. Does anyone know what dll this namespace is stored in? I was told that the namespace was in MonoDevelop.Ide.dll but when I added the dll to the MonoDevelop project the namespace did not resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This namespace doesn't exist anymore in MonoDevelop 2.4. The classes that were there have been moved to MonoDevelop.Ide.* namespaces. You can try looking in MonoDevelop.Ide, MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui, MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects or MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.OptionPanels.

Comment: Thanks for information. Do you happen to know which dll contains the class: RemoteSoftDebuggerSession?