# MonoDevelop 2.4: Help finding a dll : RemoteSoftDebuggerSession

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am trying to build a MonoDevelop 2.4 add-in but I need the dll that contains the class: RemoteSoftDebuggerSession. Does anyone know what dll this class is stored in?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436133/monodevelop-2-4-help-finding-a-dll?rq=1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.dll

Comment: Thanks! Still having issues but it is likely a configuration issue.